# INSERT - Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I'm getting:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
> match number of fields in prepared statement in
> E:\XAMPP\htdocs\account\lib\register.php on line 73

When I use this code:

```
if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO login(user, pass) VALUES(?, ?)")) {

  /* Bind parameters s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, $pw);

  /* Execute it */
  $stmt -> execute();

  /* Bind results */
  $stmt -> bind_result($user, $pw);

  /* Close statement */
  $stmt -> close();
  $userId = $conn->insert_id;
}
```

I can't understand, why this happens every time, what is wrong in my code snippet?

Comment: you are binding 3 params - in you're statement are only 2 ("?")

Comment: @niyou that's incorrect, the first is a list of types

Comment: Which line is line 73? I wouldn't expect a result from an INSERT statement, so I suspect that it's the line `$stmt -> bind_result($user, $pw);`

Comment: you're right MB - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to `bind_result` on a statement that is not returning any results.

Remove this line.
`$stmt -> bind_result($user, $pw);`